# does NULL partition contains data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Does a null partition_id contains data ?? the below table has null partition created by src

`select  partition_id from project.dataset.table where  table_name = abc and partition_id == __NULL__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NULL partition is only available in tables that are partitioned by a column in the data, not on ingestion time partitioned tables. If you are writing to a column partitioned table, you can simply not populate the value of that column in a particular row and use table_id (without any partition suffix) to write to the NULL partition.

`_ _NULL_ _` Partition: Contains rows with NULL values in the partitioning column.

**For example:**

The table is partitioned on the customer_id column into ranges of interval 10. Any rows where customer_id is NULL go into a partition named `_ _NULL_ _`.

For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables).

Comment: Why do I get a null partition_id when a table is partitioned on a required column?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you insert `null` value in a partitioned column, this `null` partition can contains data :

```sql
select partition_id from project.dataset.table 
where table_name = abc 
and partition_id is null;
```